# RGB histogram using bitshift in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, histogram, bit-shift

I'm trying to create a mozaic image in Matlab. The database consists of mostly RGB images but also some gray scale images.

I need to calculate the histograms - like in the example of the Wikipedia article about [color histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram) - for the RGB images and thought about using the bitshift operator in Matlab to combine the R,G and B channels.

```
nbins = 4;
nbits = 8;

index = bitshift(bitshift(image(:,:,1), log2(nbins)-nbits), 2*log2(nbins)) + ...
            + bitshift(bitshift(image(:,:,2), log2(nbins)-nbits), log2(nbins)) + ...
            + bitshift(image(:,:,3), log2(nbins)-nbits) + 1;
```

*index* is now a matrix of the same size as *image* with the index to the corresponding bin for the pixel value.

How can I sum the occurences of all unique values in this matrix to get the histogram of the RGB image?

Is there a better approach than bitshift to calculate the histogram of an RGB image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Calculating Indices

The `bitshift` operator seems OK to do.  Me what I would personally do is create a lookup relationship that relates RGB value to bin value.  You first have to figure out how many bins in each dimension that you want.  For example, let's say we wanted 8 bins in each channel.  This means that we would have a total of 512 bins all together.  Assuming we have 8 bits per channel, you would produce a relationship that creates an index like so:

```
% // Figure out where to split our bins
accessRed = floor(256 / NUM_RED_BINS);
accessGreen = floor(256 / NUM_GREEN_BINS);
accessBlue = floor(256 / NUM_BLUE_BINS);

%// Figures out where to index the histogram
redChan = floor(red / accessRed);
greenChan = floor(green / accessGreen);
blueChan = floor(blue / accessBlue);

%// Find single index
out = 1 + redChan + (NUM_RED_BINS)*greenChan + (NUM_RED_BINS*NUM_GREEN_BINS)*blueChan;
```

This assumes we have split our channels into `red`, `green` and `blue`.  We also offset our indices by 1 as MATLAB indexes arrays starting at 1.  This makes more sense to me, but the `bitshift` operator looks more efficient.

## Onto your histogram question

Now, supposing you have the indices stored in `index`, you can use the `accumarray` function that will help you do that.  `accumarray` takes in a set of locations in your array, as well as "weights" for each location.  `accumarray` will find the corresponding locations as well as the weights and **aggregate** them together.  In your case, you can use `sum`.  `accumarray` isn't just limited to `sum`.  You can use any operation that provides a 1-to-1 relationship.  As an example, suppose we had the following variables:

```
index =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3

weights = 

 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 3
 3
 3
 4
 4
```

What `accumarray` will do is for each value of `weights`, take a look at the corresponding value in `index`, and accumulate this value into its corresponding slot.

As such, by doing this you would get (make **sure** that `index` and `weights` are **column** vectors):

```
out = accumarray(index, weights);

out =

 6
 7
 9
 2
 2
```

If you take a look, all indices that have a value of 1, any values in `weights` that share the same index of 1 get summed into the first slot of `out`.  We have three values: 1, 2 and 3.  Similarly, with the index 2 we have values of 1, 3 and 3, which give us 7.

Now, to apply this to your application, given your code, your indices look like they start at 1.  To calculate the histogram of your image, all we have to do is set all of the weights to 1 and use `accumarray` to accumulate the entries.  Therefore:

```
%// Make sure these are column vectors
index = index(:);
weights = ones(numel(index), 1);

%// Calculate histogram
h = accumarray(index, weights);
%// You can also do:
%// h = accumarray(index, 1); - This is a special case if every value
%//                             in weights is the same number
```

`accumarray`'s behaviour by default invokes `sum`.  This should hopefully give you what you need.  Also, should there be any indices that are **missing** values, (for example, suppose the index of 2 is missing from your index matrix), `accumarray` will conveniently place a zero in this location when you aggregate.  Makes sense right?

Good luck!

Comment: The indices starts at 1 since I add 1 when calculating them ;) Accumarray was the function I was after. Thank you for a great and explanatory answer! :)

Comment: Cool.  I edited my post to reflect this.  You're very welcome.  Good luck!